# How to change /home after login in a laravel project

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, frameworks

I am new in laravel framework. I install the Auth Class in my project. So when I login in my project it goes to dashboard but url is ('/home'). I want to change this path and after login I want that it goes ('/dashboard'). For that jobs, which file I want to change? I have find 4 file where /home is decleared. Thats are web.php, LoginController.php, HomeController.php, RedirectIfAuthenticated.php. Which file I will change? or any more file there?

[Web.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7KZh.png)

[homeController.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bc99q.png)

[loginController.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8Iqa.png)

[redirectIfAuthenticated.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuDWj.png)

Answer (score 6):

There's now an easier way to do this in Laravel 6.X.

Simply change the constant in the`app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` file.

```
/**
  * The path to the "home" route for your application.
  *
  * @var string
  */
  public const HOME = '/new-url';
```

After that, change your route in your `routes/web.php` file.

```
Route::get('/new-url', 'Controller@method');

// If you don't want to use the HomeController, be sure to include the auth middleware.
Route::get('/new-url', 'Controller@method')->middleware('auth');
```

---

You can delete the `HomeController` if you're not using it in your route, won't cause any issues.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the `redirectTo` property to the LoginController, RegisterController, and ResetPasswordController files:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/';
```

It is well explained in the Laravel documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#authentication-quickstart

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this before... change the protected 
$redirecto = /home to / in the login controller, then got to routes->web and change the Route::get('/home') to Route::get('/')->name('dashboard')

or you can just change $redirecto = "/dashboard" in the login controller and make sure that you create/update a path in the routes.

Hope it helps.